# Run command with args multiple time

Tags: command-line, bash

I got a file with some params of a script:

```
foo1 a b c
foo2 a b c
foo3 a b c
```

I need to run a script once for each line in this file passing the line as script arg, so it should do:

```
./MyScript.sh foo1 a b c
./MyScript.sh foo2 a b c
./MyScript.sh foo3 a b c
```

How can I achieve this using Bash?

Comment: If what you need is to further process each line of the file and execute things accordingly, maybe `awk` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xargs` command, which is created for running a command with arguments that are read from stdin has a `--arg-file` parameter, which allows reading arguments from file. In combination with`-L1` flag, it will read your arguments file line by line, and for each line execute the command. 
Here's an example:

```
$ cat args.txt
one two three
four file six

$ xargs -L1 --arg-file=args.txt echo                       
one two three
four file six
```

Replace `echo` with your script.

Alternatively, you can always redirect the file to be read by `xargs` from stdin stream like so:

```
$ xargs -L1  echo < args.txt                                                                                             
one two three
four file six
```

Answer (score 5):

Using a `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
   # if the line read is empty 
   # go to the next line. Skips empty lines
   if [ -z "${line}" ]
   then
       continue
   fi
  /path/to/MyScript.sh $line
done < "$1"
```

Then call this script `anything.sh` and run it like this:

```
anything.sh /path/to/file/with/foo
```

Remember to make both `anything.sh` and `MyScript.sh` executable

Comment: you could directly send the file with the params to the loop: `done < params_file`

Comment: Yes I know but I prefer this so OP can change the fed in file as desired

Comment: True. I just  would not put such a simple while loop into an own script ;-) But that is a matter of taste of course.

Comment: Your for loop won't read file line by  line. Change it to `(IFS=$'\n'; for line in $(cat args.txt); do  script.sh "$line"; done)`. In general it's not the best approach.  The while loop is preferable

Comment: `[[ -n "$line" ]] && ./MyScript.sh $line` would be way shorter, 1 instead of 5 lines

Comment: @RoVo Also much more obscure. Sometimes, a few extra lines are a perfectly good trade-off when the result is much more readable, *particularly* for a beginner.